# Get first char array in a structure after typecast on other array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting, struct

Have a problem accessing some elements of a structure in a right way after typecasting.
Here my code:

```
void get_description(struct shmstruct *ptr/*, int number*/) {
    char buff[MESGSIZE];
    struct shmData *dparse;
    snprintf(buff, MESGSIZE, "%s", &ptr->msgdata[0]);
    dparse = (struct shmData *) buff;
    printf("Number: %s", dparse->number);
    printf("Description: %s", dparse->description);
}
```

Problem now is, that I get the number, like 123, but also the description in the first 
line ->
 **printf("Number: %s", dparse->number);**
like: 123 description

How can I get only the number?

(P.S.

```
struct shmData{
    char number[4];
    char description[1020];
};
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the number is not nul-terminated.  You have the `number` field and then immediately following you have the `description` field.  `printf()` assumes that you are giving it a nul-terminated string, and it will keep going until it hits the terminating nul character.  It looks like in your case, there isn't a nul terminating the `number` field, so `printf()` just keeps going and gets the `description` also.

Can all four characters from `number` be used for digits?

If the numbers are only 3-digits or fewer, then you can put a terminating nul right into the `number` buffer.  If you might need to read a 4-digit number from there, you need to copy out the digits into a temp buffer of at least 5 chars, and then nul-terminate.

```
// max 3 digits:
dparse->number[3] = '\0'; // ensure nul-termination of number

// max 4 digits:
#define DPARSE_NUMBER 4  /* size of number field in dparse */
char temp[DPARSE_NUMBER + 1];
strncpy(temp, dparse->number, sizeof(temp));
temp[sizeof(temp) - 1] = '\0'; // strncpy() does not guarantee to nul-terminate, so we must do this
```

`strncpy()` doesn't guarantee to nul-terminate, which is unfortunate.  So we should always put in a terminating nul character in the last position so that no matter what, it is nul-terminated.  Note that sometimes `strncpy()` will put a nul for us, but it does no harm to make sure one is there.

Comment: There can be a 4-digit number. Is there a simple way to do?

Comment: Ok, I've made it garbage_style:

Comment: char temp[4];
 temp[0] = dparse->number[0];
 temp[1] = dparse->number[1];
 temp[2] = dparse->number[2];
 temp[3] = dparse->number[3];
 printf("Number: %s\n", temp);

Comment: As you can see, I updated my answer to use `strncpy()`.  For a short string of 4 characters, the way you did it isn't too bad, but the solution using `strncpy()` is a nice general solution that works for very long strings also.